# How to delete photos from iPhoto/Phots with a particular filename format?

Tags: photos, photos.app, resolution

I have a phone that stores 2 images every time I take a picture. One is a high resolution photo and the other is a low resolution photo.
When I connect my phone to the mac, it imports all the photos into iPhotos, Photos and into the Pictures folder.
I want to keep only the high resolution photos and delete the low resolution ones.
.
A sample of the file name format for the 2 images is shown below.

- WP_20150402_16_44_11_Pro__highres.jpg
- WP_20150402_16_44_11_Pro.jpg

I can very easily delete the low resolution photos from the Pictures folder.
**How do I do the same in iPhotos and Photos app?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure either iPhoto or Photos would be keen on you deleting pictures from inside the app folder framework.

They both expect to be 'in charge' of the editing & deleting process.

I think, long term it may be better, if you want your 'originals' in a single format in each of the 3 locations to use Image Capture to do the import, to a distinct 4th location; folder on the desktop etc.

Then do your file trimming & only afterwards import to iPhoto, Photos & finally move the files to your Pictures folder.

Automator might be best to do the initial file cull.

This example 'Folder Action' will throw out anything NOT containing '_highres'
Note the 'None' parameter in the filter, circled in red.
Folder Actions will trigger every time the Target folder is changed, by adding or removing content.

[image]

Comment: I have done this already for the Pictures folder. I need a way to do this for iPhotos and Photos app. Can I use automator to do this?

Comment: You could - but I'm pretty sure it will upset both apps. They really do want to be in charge. 'Proper' method would be to delete from inside the app, which wouldn't be automateable, afaik

Comment: You said 'You could...'. Can you elaborate on it further. I have a backup in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Just use the Library 'file' as your target folder, then same as above - but you need to be certain that all the photos have a 'low' & a highres version, as the only way it's filtering is 'if not highres, delete'